# Postgres - ORA-08177

Tags: postgresql, oracle-fdw

I have a foreign table set up which points to a table in an Oracle DB.   This very annoying error is being thrown:

```
ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
```

I have done some reading and one of the suggestions is:

```
alter server ni00dev options ( set isolation_level 'read_committed ');
```

However, that does not seem to work:

```
zrec=# alter server ni00dev options ( set isolation_level 'read_committed ');
ERROR:  option "isolation_level" not found
```

Any suggestions on how to get rid of the ORA-08177?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can only `SET` an option to a value if you already had the option defined. Otherwise, you need to `ADD` it. Also, the option value must not contain an extra space character.

```
ALTER SERVER ni00dev OPTIONS (ADD isolation_level 'read_committed');
```

Note that you need at lease oracle_fdw version 2.3.0 for this option. It is always recommended to run the latest version of oracle_fdw.

Comment: I wonder if this is a version issue?    zrec=# ALTER SERVER ni00dev OPTIONS (ADD isolation_level 'read_committed');
ERROR:  invalid option "isolation_level"

Comment: Very likely. But you didn't tell us that important detail.

Comment: psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.10  -- If this version is too early for "read_commited", are there any other solutions?

Comment: The oracle_fdw version. See the documentation how to get it. Also, add new information to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: @LandonStatis please keep in mind that PostgreSQL 10.10 is nearly five years old and EOL since more than a year. Please update your system!